# Как проверить наличие значения переменной в списке?

Tags: python

Допустим есть такой код:

```
variable = 'Яблоко'
mylist = ['Морковь', 'Яблоко', 'Мандарин']
```

Как проверить, есть ли значение, равное значению переменной в списке?

Извиняюсь за столь глупый вопрос :)

Comment: попробуйте так `variable  in mylist`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дополню комментарий к Вашему вопросу. Действительно, самый лёгкий способ - использовать оператор `in`: `variable in mylist` (вызывает `mylist.__exists__`).

Также можно использовать метод list.count() в конструкции if наподобии:

```
if mylist.count(variable) > 0:
    ...
```